# nvim: Как открыть документацию nvim во весь экран

Tags: vim

Когда читаешь документацию командой :help, она открывается сверху. Если перенести курсор в прошлое окно и выполнить :q, то закрываются оба окна. Как добиться того, чтобы документация была во весь экран?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы закрыть все остальные окна и сделать текущее окно единственным на экране, можете либо ввести команду `:on` (это сокращённо, а полностью: `:only`), либо нажать сочетание <kbd>ctrl+w</kbd>, а затем <kbd>o</kbd>.

справка:

```
:h :on
```

или [онлайн](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_o)

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно!